# Java - URLDecoder.decode(String s) vs URLDecoder.decode(String s, String enc)

Tags: java, urldecode

What is the difference between

```
URLDecoder.decode(String s)
```

and

```
URLDecoder.decode(String s, String enc)
```

I had a cookie value like

```
val=%22myvalue%22
```

I am retrieving it:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

String val = cookies[0].getValue();
```

But the value of `val` is `%22myvalue%22`

So I tried `URLDecoder`:

```
String val1 = URLDecoder.decode(val);
String val2 = URLDecoder.decode(val, "utf8");
```

And values of both are same, that is `myvalue`

So what is the difference between both?

Comment: `URLDecoder.decode(String s)` is deprecated due to unexpected behavior on uncertain encodings.

Comment: So the other is better?

Comment: Using deprecated Methods/Classes is always a bad idea, since they are subject to complete deletion in further versions. That's why they are deprecated for a while. Shortly: YES!

Comment: @AxelAmthor Good and brief explanation for deprecated methods / classes. +1 on comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> URLDecoder.decode(String s)

Decodes a x-www-form-urlencoded string. The platform's default encoding is used to determine what characters are represented by any consecutive sequences of the form "%xy".

Note: It is deprecated.

> URLDecoder.decode(String s, String enc)

Decodes a application/x-www-form-urlencoded string using a specific encoding scheme. The supplied encoding is used to determine what characters are represented by any consecutive sequences of the form "%xy".

Entire info you can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html).

Comment: This is just reproducing the documentation. It adds nothing to explain why the decoded value is the same.