# URLDecoder.decode not working as expected

Tags: java, javascript, maven, spring-mvc, encoding

I am trying to pass a search string from the javascript front end to a java controller which accesses another api.

Everything was running except for string with special characters ex "test+123".

i fixed this using encoding / decoding to try to solve this bug. I am using a combination of JavaScript encodeURIComponent() (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) , and Java URLDecoder (http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Additionally I looked at this:
[Java - URLDecoder.decode(String s) vs URLDecoder.decode(String s, String enc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309930/java-urldecoder-decodestring-s-vs-urldecoder-decodestring-s-string-enc)

they use "utf8" (UrlDecoder.decode(string,"utf8");)

I tested just using **just the javascript encode** which turns my string "test+123" into something that pulls up a bunch of correct results.

My logger states that the correct search string is being searched upon.

Ex "test+123": 
Without encode javascript -> "test 123"

With javascript encode -> "test+123"

With Java decode -> No result?

My Javascript code looks like this:

```
var encodedString=encodeURIComponent($("#search-input").val());
```

My Java code looks like:

```
String result = URLDecoder.decode(encodedSearchString,"utf8");
```

I checked the debugger and my logger is correct, encodedSearchString is not encoded.

What's going on?

I haven't written any other code relating to encoding or decoding, I don't see that occurring anywhere else in the code. I'm using **spring mvc, maven, and intellj** if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

The interesting reason for why this was not returning correct results is the tech stack itself.

Spring MVC contains it's own decoder that is automatically on (it must be manually turned off) see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Quote from above link
"urlDecode Defaults to true, as of Spring 2.5. If you prefer to compare encoded paths, set this flag to false. However, the HttpServletRequest always exposes the Servlet path in decoded form. Be aware that the Servlet path will not match when compared with encoded paths."

There was essentially something underneath that was not visibly encoded. Thus decoding the message strings is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the syntax must be UTF-8 instead of utf8 ?

String result = URLDecoder.decode(encodedSearchString,"UTF-8");

Comment: I tried playing with the utf, as well as using the deprecated .decode(string) in an effort to eliminate that variable :( unfortunately that doesn't appear to be the problem.